# Mongodb + PHP Failed to send "find" command with database "Czechia": Failed to read 4 bytes: socket error or timeout

Tags: mongodb, sockets, timeout

I have a PHP script which should send about 2 millions of items from MongoDB to Elasticsearch. There is a loop where one iteration needs to make 4 requests to the MongoDB where the query simply calls

```
{"ico": {$in: [here are 50 items]}}
// collection has about 2M items and ico is indexed
```

But it still ends up on this error **Failed to read 4 bytes: socket error or timeout** - MongoDB version is 4, PHP version 7.1.

What does that mean? Are 50 items with $in query too much if collection has about 2 million items? How to solve it?